# Elastic search load csv data with context

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have 3m records. Headers are `value, type, other_fields`..

Here I need to load the data as in [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/suggester-context.html#suggester-context-category)

I need to specify `type` as context for that `value` in the record. Is there any way to do this with log stash? or any other options?

```
val,val_type,id
Sunnyvale it labs, seller, 10223667
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, I'd use the new [CSV ingest processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/csv-processor.html)

First create the ingest pipeline to parse your CSV data

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/csv-parser
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "csv": {
        "field": "message",
        "target_fields": [
          "val",
          "val_type",
          "id"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "script": {
        "source": """
          def val = ctx.val;
          ctx.val = [
            'input': val,
            'contexts': [
              'type': [ctx.val_type]
            ]
          ]
          """
      }
    },
    {
      "remove": {
        "field": "message"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, you can index your documents as follow:

```
PUT index/_doc/1?pipeline=csv-parser
{
  "message": "Sunnyvale it labs,seller,10223667"
}
```

After ingestion, the document will look like this:

```
{
  "val_type": "seller",
  "id": "10223667",
  "val": {
    "input": "Sunnyvale it labs",
    "contexts": {
      "type": [
        "seller"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE: Logstash solution**

Using Logstash, it's also feasible. The configuration file would look something like this:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/path/to/your/file.csv"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}
filter {
    csv {
        skip_header => true
        separator => ","
        columns => ["val", "val_type", "id"]
    }
    mutate {
        rename => { "val" => "value" }
        add_field => { 
            "[val][input]" => "%{value}" 
            "[val][contexts][type]" => "%{val_type}" 
        }
        remove_field => [ "value" ]
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
        index => "your-index"
    }    
}
```

Comment: When I try this with postman I see two different errors. 1. It says `post` is not allowed. 2. It says error with `script` portion which expects comma after `source`. In the meantime, I ll also look for the solution.

Comment: Actually, this needs to be run inside Kibana Dev Tools (because of the triple quotes). If you want to remove the triple quotes, you can but you also need to remove all the carriage return characters within the script.

Comment: How should I enclose the other words inside context? I am not aware of `Kibana` :( Can I do this with only log stash and ES?

Comment: You can run the above in Postman too if needed, just read my earlier comment

Comment: I've also provided a Logstash-only solution

Comment: And, should I have `suggest` or `value` in that `mutate`? I thought `suggest` in documentation specifies a field. Isn't Val?

Comment: Can you show a specific line of your CSV and how you'd like it to be stored?

Comment: There is a mistake which I resolved now - `"[val][contexts][type]" => "%{val_type}" ` should be `"[val][contexts][val_type]" => "%{val_type}" `

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out!