# Elasticsearch - split by comma - split filter Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a field where values are dynamic. I want to store space separated tokens in an array field for `completion suggester`

Let's say if my field `val` is `hi how are you` then I want to have an array with `[hi how are you, how are you, are you, you]`

I tried with `split filter` as my data in `csv`. I couldn't achieve that. Is there anyway to do this with only ES, Logstash.

Comment: You can achieve it with the same solution I gave you the other day: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62211180/4604579 . Just use the script processor to create your shingles array

Comment: I couldn't find a way to split using script processor. Could you please point me a reference?

Comment: As mentioned, I would use the script processor and do the splitting job using scripting, because you need some logic there.

Comment: I think you mean [this page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/painless-api-reference-shared-java-lang.html#painless-api-reference-shared-String)

Comment: I mean this processor: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/script-processor.html

Comment: So, I should use `painless` language in `script processor` to achieve `split` logic. I will try further

Comment: Yes, that's what I would do since you need some special logic to achieve what you want

Comment: And You mentioned earlier that I need `Kibana` to do something like [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/painless-walkthrough.html#_accessing_doc_values_from_painless). Because of '''. Can I do the same with only Logstash?

Comment: You don't need Kibana, with the triple quotes, the scripts are just more legible, that's all, but they only work in Kibana. I guess you can do the same in Logstash using some logic in the `ruby` filter

Comment: @Val I am struggling to make `script {
    source : """
      ctx.val_tokens = ctx.val.splitOnToken(" ")
      """
  }` syntax correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the solution I linked to, you can achieve what you need as follows.

First create an ingest pipeline that leverages the `script` processor to build the desired input array:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/csv-parser
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "csv": {
        "field": "message",
        "target_fields": [
          "val",
          "val_type",
          "id"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "script": {
        "source": """
          def tokens = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(/\s+/.split(ctx.val)));
          def nbTokens = tokens.size();
          def input = [];
          for (def i = nbTokens; i > 0; i--) {
            input.add(tokens.join(" "));
            tokens.remove(0);
          }

          ctx.val = [
            'input': input,
            'contexts': [
              'type': [ctx.val_type]
            ]
          ]
          """
      }
    },
    {
      "remove": {
        "field": "message"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you can index documents like this:

```
PUT index/_doc/1?pipeline=csv-parser
{
  "message": "hi how are you,seller,10223667"
}
```

And the resulting document will look like this:

```
GET index/_doc/1
->
{
    "val" : {
      "input" : [
        "hi how are you",
        "how are you",
        "are you",
        "you"
      ],
      "contexts" : {
        "type" : [
          "seller"
        ]
      }
    },
    "val_type" : "seller",
    "id" : "10223667"
}
```

Comment: You are helping me a lot. My trouble is that how to make it part of syntactically correct logstash conf? I had the same problem with my previous ques also. Is there any doc to refer that for script filter in logstash conf?

Comment: So you really don't want to use ingest pipelines then?

Comment: If I use ingest pipeline, I cannot load my build data from CSV. Correct? Ingest pipeline is needed when I make it even based loading like in real time production. Isn't?

Comment: Using ingest pipeline, you can definitely import your CSV (thanks to the csv processor)... Instead of having logic in your Logstash config, you have the logic in the ingest pipeline, which makes your Logstash config simpler, just read from CSV file and send it as it to ES which does the job

Comment: Yeah! Is it pipeline option of ES output plugin. Am I correct? I will explore it right away

Comment: I end up with that same issue `"""`. I get the below from `curl` and `postman` also. `{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to parse content to map"}],"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to parse content to map","caused_by":{"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Unexpected character ('\"' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@7de1d817; line: 17, column: 22]"}},"status":400}`

Comment: I got a lead by keeping all the lines in one line.

Comment: Ok great, now you need to replace `join(" ")` by `join(' ')` (with single quote)

Comment: My real problem starts now, When I load data with the plugin, previous data is overwritten - only `val` got changed. Means only one record gets inserted with changing `val`

Comment: I added the plugin with little alteration of `csv` plugin like addition of other fields and order of the fields. Then I removed `csv` portion in my `Logstash conf` and just kept `input` and `output` with `pipeline`

Comment: I got that working. :) I will definitely need your help in the future.

Comment: Great, glad you figured it out!